# akka tcp server-client heartbeat message block by scheduler processing

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-cluster, akka-actor, akka-tcp

I am using Akka cluster (Server) and exchanging HeartBeat message with client using Akka TCP in every 5 seconds.

HeartBeat is working fine till I am not using scheduler. 
but when I am starting 4-5 schedulers, Server is not receiving heartbeat buffer message from client (tcp connection). After scheduler processing, I am getting 4-5 heartbeat messages at same time.

Akka sceduler is blocking actor other processing (buffer reading etc).

I already tried below, but still facing same issue.

1. different-2 dispatcher
2. created new actor and added scheduler call in seperate actor.
3. using 8 core machine
4. tried `fork-join-executor` and `thread-pool-executor`
5. already tried changing `Tcp-SO-ReceivedBufferSize` and `Tcp-SO-SendBufferSize` to 1024 or 2048, but it didn’t work.
6. already tried `Tcp-SO-TcpNoDelay`

Kindly help.

Comment: Why are you starting 4-5 scheduler ?

Comment: can you elaborate why you need 4 to 5 schedulers , like what the scheduler is doing here?